# Formula that calculates the difference between numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create a formula that would be able to calculate the difference between the numbers and writes it exactly as shown in this image: https://i.postimg.cc/W4cZDgD2/image.png

Full Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eikT6wwBSVfjxkXQeXWFjrkBgedAepAtXch-Fq_UdgQ

I sew home-made large stuffed animals and I need it to evenly sew some parts.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The desired results shown in the sample spreadsheet do not appear consistent. If they really are the correct results, please explain _why_ the patterns shown in the desired results differ between the first two and the last two cases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will match the first two cases:

```
=arrayformula(join(" - "; filter(C4:K4 - B4:J4; isnumber(C4:K4)); B4))
```

This formula will match the last two cases:

```
=arrayformula(join(" - "; B4; filter(C4:K4 - B4:J4; isnumber(C4:K4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will work for all the variations.

## Locale: Czechia, France, etc.

Any locale that uses `,` as the decimal separator

```
=LET(r;A10:J10; JOIN(" - "; 
  FILTER({r\0}-{0\r}; LEN({r\""})>0)))
```

## Locale: North America

Any locale that uses `.` as the decimal separator

```
LET(r,A10:J10, JOIN(" - ", 
  FILTER({r,0}-{0,r}, LEN({r,""})>0)))
```